# How to apply css style to custom attributes

Tags: jquery, css

```
<p target="a"><a>A</a></p>
<p target="b"><a>B</a></p>
<p target="c"><a>C</a></p>
<p target="d" ><a>D</a></p>
<p target="e"><a>E</a></p>
```

and i can select a custom attribute like this

```
$($(this).attr('target'))
```

But how can i add style to this, 
I've tried `$($(this).attr('target')).css()` but its not working.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `$(this)`at `$(this).attr('target')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute equals selector

```
$("[target=" + $(this).attr("target") + "]").css(/*propertyName [, propertyValue]*/)
```